# Добавление строки в tableview JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Как добавить в TableView еще один элемент,то есть когда надо выгрузить Лист с этим прекрасно справляется setItems но появилась необходимость добавить, а в будущем и удалить строку из таблицы как это можно сделать!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё достаточно просто, предположим у вас таблица заполнена данными типа Test, тогда:

```
ObservableList<Test> tableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
TableView<Test> table = new TableView<>(tableData);

Test test = new Test();
tableData.add(test); // добавить строку
tableData.remove(test); // удалить строку, которую только что добавили
```

Вот пример @FXML контроллера для таблицы:

```
public class FXMLTableViewController {
    @FXML private TableView<User> tableView;

    @FXML
    protected void addUser(ActionEvent event) {
        ObservableList<User> data = tableView.getItems(); // получаем данные
        data.add(new User()); // добавляем строку
    }
}
```

Comment: (@FXML    private TableView<User> table;) Проблема в том, что TableView используется в контроллере и как я понимаю грузятся в начале все переменные под тегом @FXML  а уже потом ObservableList<Test> .ObservableList<Test> у меня инициализируется из другого класса я попробавл его передать в этот класс и уже в методе передачи данных TableView<Test> передал этот ObservableList<Test> и начал добавлять данные но в таблице они не выводяться!(
'public void setMainApp(Osnova main,ObservableList<User> uu) {
        this.osnova = main;
        this.uu=uu;
        table =new TableView<User>(uu);'

Comment: @Георгий, я дополнил ответ. Посмотрите, там написан пример контроллера, который добавляет строку в таблицу.

Comment: спасибо работает!setitems почему то не срабатывает!)но я выгрузил все через add!))